# ERROR : Spectrum nested query error. A subquery that refers to a nested table cannot contain DISTINCT operation. Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

When I run this query I get the above error message, which happens only on Redshift. Is there any other method to select the distinct items in a nested query?

```
select distinct(cast(A.id as varchar)) from db1.table1 A
  join
  (
     select 
         distinct(properties.event_id) from events.table2
     where 
      properties.event_screen in (' xxxxxxxxxxxx ',' yyyyyyyyyyyy ')                        
     and properties.category_ID in (' zzzzzzzzz ',' aaaaaaaaaaaa ')
     and date(dt) between date_add('day',-29,current_date) and date_add('day',0,current_date) 
  )  as B
  on A.key = B.event_id
```

Comment: I see an even bigger problem here which is that your `B` subquery does not select any column called `id`, so I would actually expect the exact code you pasted above to fail.  Can you show us the actual code?

Comment: my bad, fixed it

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and applies to the whole selected rows. Simply write `select distinct cast(A.id as varchar) from ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: Presumably, you are using Redshift and the MySQL tag was extraneous.  I removed it.  Sample data and desired results would help.  For instance, what is `properties`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the requirement of using a `JOIN` or `DISTINCT` here.

You can use `IN` as follows:

```
select distinct(cast(c.id as varchar)) from db1.table1 A
  WHERE A.key IN -- used IN
  (
     select 
         properties.event_id AS ID -- CONSIDERING THIS AS ID
         from events.table2
     where 
      properties.event_screen in (' xxxxxxxxxxxx ',' yyyyyyyyyyyy ')                        
     and properties.category_ID in (' zzzzzzzzz ',' aaaaaaaaaaaa ')
     and date(dt) between date_add('day',-29,current_date) and date_add('day',0,current_date) 
  )
```

Comment: I got an error `(NOT) IN subquery is not supported`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
select A.id
from db1.table1 A join
     (select  distinct properties.event_id
      from events.table2 t2
      where properties.event_screen in ('xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'yyyyyyyyyyyy') and                     
            properties.category_ID in ('zzzzzzzzz', 'aaaaaaaaaaaa') and
            dt >= date_add('day', -29, current_date) and 
            dt < date_add('day', 1, current_date) 
      ) B
      on A.key = B.event_id;
```

Notes:

- This assumes that `properties` is a nested structure in `table2`.
- The conversion to a string seems superfluous.
- For an `id` column, I don't see why `select distinct` is needed at all.
- I changed the date arithmetic to avoid the function call on `dt`.